# Adding files to GitHub does not update the Releases Assets source code

Tags: github, composer-php, packagist

Using GitHub via a browser, I am failing to create the Releases assets source code zip and tar.gz files that contain my src/filename.php files.
Syncing to Packagist appears to work OK, but Composer then not unexpectedly fails to load my source files into the usual vendor/packagename/src/ subdirectory.

I have tried loading the source files themselves into the main part of the repository into subdirectory  /src using Add file. I have also added a zipped and a tarballed version into Releases file upload.

GitHub documentation is somewhat light on this, so could someone kindly explain exactly what I am doing wrong.

Comment: A release on GitHub is associated with a tag.  Are you changing the contents of the tag, or are you just pushing additional data to the main branch?

Comment: Please share more details - is there any error message given?

Answer (score 0):

My finger trouble somewhere...

I was indeed incrementing the tag version, but it seems as if the php code additions I did to the main branch (with file upload) had for some unfathomable reason be made AFTER the new tag (release). Packagist then synched to the new tagged version but this was obviously missing the code additions.
My remedy was simply to methodically update the code again, check the json for tag version, and then finally release with an incremented tag.

Incidentally, there was no error message - just a total absence of php modules in my myvendor/mypackagename/src !